# Localize Biblatex time format by language, 12h vs 24h

Tags: biblatex, locale

Inside a Biblatex `.lbx` file, is there a way to change the default package option to `{time=12h}`?

While working on localization strings in `.lbx` files for a Biblatex style, I'm trying to be both economical and complete in the changes. By default, English documents in this style ought to have "a.m." or "p.m." printed after times given in 12-hour format, but most other languages should have time printed in a 24-hour format; this second option is Biblatex's default for all languages. Since an option like formatting the display of time is ultimately a matter of localization, is it possible to define a default state in the localization files in a way that is still responsive to a user's explicit settings?

I know it can be set it in the `.bbx` file using `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`, but this change is unresponsive to the language of a document, which is defined by the user. Likewise, I can add the following line to bibliography extras in my `.lbx` file, but then it becomes hard coded, ignoring user declarations:

```
\blx@kv@setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{time=12h}%
```

Ideally, changing the language would change the default presentation of time while still honoring any options declared explicitly. Have I overlooked something obvious, or is it possible through non-obvious means?